# React-TypeScript: Property 'geo' is missing in type '{}' but required in type 'IMapProps

Tags: typescript, google-maps, react-typescript

I am practicing React-Typescript. In my React app, I fetched the data from [json placeholder API](https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users) and from that API I want to use the geo location's lat and lng and pass it to My Map component. In my Map component I used [google-map-react](https://www.npmjs.com/package/google-map-react). I successfully displayed the map. In my Map component, I made an interface prop which is like this:

```
export interface IMapProps {
  geo: {
    lat: number;
    lng: number;
  }
}
```

If I made geo optional like `geo?:` The Map appeared but If made geo required I got error like this: `Property 'geo' is missing in type '{}' but required in type 'IMapProps`. Also, I don't know how to use the Props in TypeScript.

**This is my Parent component where I fetched the data and planning to pass the Map component.**

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import Map from './Map'
export interface Data {
  id: number;
  name: string;
  username: string;
  email: string;
  address: {
    street: string;
    suite: string;
    city: string;
    zipcode: number;
    geo: {
      lat: number;
      lng: number;
    };
  };
  phone: number;
  website: string;
  company: {
    name: string;
    catchPhrase: string;
    bs: string;
  };
};

const Parent = () => {
  const [state, setState] = useState<Data[]>([])
  useEffect(() => {
    getData()
  }, [])
  const getData = async () => {
    const response = await fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users");
    const data = await response.json();
    console.log(data);
    setState(data);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      {state.map(i => <Map geo={i.address.geo} />)} //IN HERE I am passing the props to the Map component. But after that I don't know how to use to porps in TypeScript

    </div>
  )
}



export default Parent
```

**This is My Map component where I would like to use my props.**

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import GoogleMapReact from 'google-map-react';
import Marker from './Marker'
export interface IMapProps {
  geo: {
    lat: number;
    lng: number;
  }
}

const Maps = ({ geo }: IMapProps) => {

  const [state, setstate] = useState(
    {
      center: {
        lat: 60.1098678,
        lng: 24.7385084
      },
      zoom: 7
    }
  )

  return (

    <div >
      <div style={{ height: '100vh', width: '100%' }}>
        <GoogleMapReact
          bootstrapURLKeys={{ key: "**********" }}
          defaultCenter={state.center}
          defaultZoom={state.zoom}
        >
          <Marker
            lat={state.center.lat}
            lng={state.center.lng}
            text="My Marker" />
        </GoogleMapReact>
      </div>
    </div>


  );
};



export default Maps;
```

Comment: For the `geo={i.address.geo}`, where does the `i` come from?

Comment: It will help you understand what I meant: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map

Comment: Ahh yes just saw the there is the array.map there

Comment: Yes mate. Try to figure out how to use the props in child component. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Actually I just figured it out :D

Comment: Cool! Good to hear!!

Answer (score 0):

If you set the `geo` mandatory, the child component requires the `geo` property with lat and long properties. So say, when the parent component has not finished the axios call, your parent `state` is initialized to `[]` and your `i.address.geo` is basically undefined and that raises the error.

Ways To Fix:

1. You can keep the `geo` optional in child component.
2. Or, you can have an initial `geo` type value in your parent `state`. i.e.

```
const [state, setState] = useState<any>({'address': {'geo': {
        lat: 60.1098678,
        lng: 24.7385084
      }}})
```

Comment: I already initialized geo in the parent component's interface.

Comment: **const Parent = () => {
  const [state, setState] = useState<Data[]>([]) ...** - this is initialized as **[]** not with geo

Comment: Also, I think you can not initialize inside the component interface. In the interface, you declare types only. Hope this is helpful

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. Can you please show me how to use the props in Map component?